# Custom listview with different container based on server response

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, controller, containers

I am creating a listview.

I have 16 different widgets (i.e.image button,label,circular image).

Listview's row can have any of these at a time based on the response.
for example if the response have only image button and label ,list view's each row will have only these 2 items.

But the response can change and next time i might get 3 different widgets for the list view.
Widgets positions will be given in response only,based on that i have to set up the position of widgets in a listview row.

Please suggest.

Comment: You just need to write an adapter (maybe extending BaseAdapter) that constructs the correct View to represent each item. If you have a small set of possible views, then you can use getItemViewType to load different layouts. Or you could have a simple root view for all rows, and then add your widgets dynamically.

Comment: Bruce, using getItemViewtype is not possible since i do not know which combination of widgets i will get for listview.I am adding the widgets dynamically but that will have impact on performance since for each row it is constructing the view rather than using the previous view.Is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: Well, you could have a root view that gets recycled, and each time you could remove all the dynamic child views. But it's not going to have a great performance. If a particular item always has the same combination of widgets, and if there is a reasonable set of possible combinations, then getItemViewType would help. But if that's really not possible, then removing all the widgets and re-adding them each time is the best you can do.

Comment: @Gaurav-goyal, Hi..! Was chckng the other questions, you had asked pertaining to smooth scrolling, which you could have posted here itself as a single question..!  :/

Comment: @Mannii88 I think that question is not linked to this at all. May be i could not put that question in good words.

Comment: Else these details could have been added there on what you were trying and why you felt listview didn't offer the smooth scrolling you had expected.! :-)